# Query inner join with Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax

I have 2 tables

Table 1

> tblpaket : jenis

Table 2

> produk : kd_jenis, nm_jenis

How to display all data in `tblpaket` and one field `in nm_jenis` with `tblpaket.jenis` same as `kd_jenis`

Because I have many fields I am only displaying 3 fields. So I want to display the `nm_produk` field from the `tblpaket` table where the `jenis` record in the `tblpaket` table is the same as the `kd_type` in table product record. With

```
select * from tblpaket
```

because I want display all field in `tblpaket` and one field `nm_produk` in table `produk` where table `jenis` field same as table `tblproduk` field `kd_jenis`

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  However, you seem to want a simple `JOIN`.

Comment: Your question is unclear.. [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: any syntax to display all fields tblpaket and 1 field nm_produk in table produk. Where field jenis in the table paket = kd_jenis in the product table.

Comment: Please help create the syntax

Comment: By the way, tables have *columns*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you need to join `TBLPAKET` to `PRODUK`. You've asked for different things, so I'm not sure I understand your requirements exactly, but based on your last comment it appears you want to do something like

```
SELECT t.*, p.NM_PRODUK
  FROM TBLPAKET t
  INNER JOIN PRODUK p
    ON p.KD_JENIS = t.JENIS
```

If this isn't quite what you had in mind, feel free to adjust it as needed.

Best of luck.